# How to set up Magento on a Amazon Web Service Hosting with CentOS?

Tags: magento, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, centos

I have to set up a dev/test platform on the Amazon Web Service. So I was told, "install it" but I have no clue how to do that. I'm very used to 1&1, OVH and other hosting companies on which I upload my data through FileZilla but here it seems to be completely different. Am I wrong?

I read that I would need to install centOS to communicate with the server, right? is there no other way to do so? FileZilla?

And By the Way, how do I set up Magento on AWS? I found some documentation about it :

http://loadstorm.com/2009/magento-setup-amazon-associates-web-service

http://www.zetaprints.com/magentohelp/category/overview/

http://www.greengecko.co.nz/magento_on_amazon_ec2

But each time, it seems that I missed something in the first lines, the VERY FIRST step.
Could someone enlightene me please because I think I missed something at the starting point of this process and I clearly don't understand the way it works.

I downloaded both elasticFirefox extension and S3 organizer, but they are not very helpful for the understanding. In each of the docs I have read, the guy starts from a point I can't reach ..

PS: I've started developing the website with Magento so it is about transfering this version of Magento instead of installing a new one .. except if it's much much more complicated ..

Any Help or full documentation would be appreciated :)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something very much alike (using CentOS 5.5 on rackspase) - follow the steps below. all the lines that start with "--" should be treated as remarks. Before you start "transferring" Magento you should install PHP, httpd and MySql:

-- MySql

```
yum install mysql-server
```

-- httpd

```
yum install httpd
```

-- open port 80 in iptables

```
vi  /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

-- add a line:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

-- configure httpd.conf (enable the use of .htaccess)

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

change the line under “< Directory "/var/www/html >” from “AllowOverride None” to “AllowOverride All”

-- install php 5

```
rpm -ivh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/`uname -i`/webtatic-release-5-1.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-mysql
```

-- go to /var/www/html

```
cd /var/www/html
```

-- and copy there all the content of Magento
--then clean cache if any:

```
rm -rf /var/www/html/<your app>/var/cache/*
```

-- you have to create a schema:

```
mysql
mysql> create database [your schema name];
mysql> grant all privileges on [your schema name].* to [your username]@localhost identified by '[your password]';
```

-- create sql dump on your computer:

```
mysqldump [your schema name] > [your schema name].sql
```

-- and import it on centos

```
mysql [your schema name] <   [your schema name].sql;
```

--Make sure that the username/password are configured properly:

```
vi <your app>/app/etc/local.xml
```

-- Login the DB as [your user]:

```
mysql -u [your user] –p
```

-- Locate the entry that is configured to localhost (since you developed it on your computer) and change it to the installation-server’s IP (say 1.1.1.1):

```
select path, value from [your schema name].core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';
update [your schema name].core_config_data set value = 'http:/<your domain>/<your app>/' where path like '%base_url%';
```

-- now restart all the services

```
service iptables restart
service mysqld restart
service httpd restart
```

-- Troubleshooting

```
In order to print error to screen follow these steps:
cd /var/www/html/<your app>/errors
cp local.xml.sample local.xml
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I dont really know how to use it for now but I guess it will be very helpful soon.
BUT, that doesn t really enligh me on every points : Do I have to use centOS ? why ? why should I use it when I never needed it before to do the same thing (transfer files) ? Do I have to enter those lines once mu centOS installation is done ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the server that Amazon provides you has centOS installed (clean environment with centOS as the operating-system). You should have received from Amazon an admin username and password to the virtual server (use it for ssh connection). using this admin user - you can follow the "script" I wrote and install all the required components in order to run Magento. This is totally different than having Magento run on your local windows machine!

Comment: Thank You, I understand. But what is really the difference between this method and the classic ftp method with filezilla ? Do I have to learn centOS or your script is enought to do whatever I need to do with Magento ?

Comment: you can't install httpd,php and mysql using ftp. only after you prepare the environment - Magento will work.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read this first which would solve your transfer to S3 question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855109/amazon-s3-ftp-interface

Comment: All right, thanks, so S3 is a kind of filezilla for this cloud computing solution right ? I have to transfer the datas with S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a couple clicks using a [Bitnami AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/magento) or their [cloud hosting tool](http://bitnami.org/cloud)