# How to create tables in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I am going to start Joomla for some work. I never tried Joomla before this. I got a source code but I stuck in the creation of table. How can I create tables using command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a table" - are you talking about DB table ? HTML table ? show us your code

Comment: DB table. I got an application code written by my friend. Now I want to run this application on my machine. When I tried to run it throws an error "table abc_session" doesnot exist. So, How can I create table, if I have source code.

Comment: It isn't as simple as you think it is.  Firstly, we do need to see the code, but only what's relevant.

Comment: Read my answer [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9794884/1057429) - the part that is relevant for you (even though the question deals with Magento, not Joomla) is all the lines with `mysql` and `mysqldump`

Comment: please provide any code you have already tried to create tables with, THEN we will be able to help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should start with the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/), it will create most of the files you need for a custom component.