# PHP not working on Linux

Tags: php, linux, web

I don't know why is this code giving me a blank page:

```
<?php

    echo "Hello World";

?>
```

I have PHP5 and Apache2 installed. I'm using Linux Mint and Aptana Studio. I've search for the solution but couldn't find anything.

This is the output for the "php -i":

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4

System => Linux vaz-softengineer 3.5.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 8 22:07:55 UTC 2013 x86_64
Build Date => Sep  4 2013 19:34:43
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini

PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20100525 => /usr/lib/php5/20100525
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear => .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => -1 => -1
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => On => On
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Europe/Paris

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dba

DBA support => enabled
Supported handlers => cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
dba.default_handler => flatfile => flatfile

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.8.0
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: e523cdc8829892d1b4f9cb7c3c57b2ba1c36b9ea $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.15

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.8.0
libXML Loaded Version => 20800
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 4.7.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mhash

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.30 2012-02-04

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers =>  

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: 2a47d3d0354109d8077e34d59f1228ccfd021d59 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: 967584c6fadb3467f31abe8e13caa8764df85867 $

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: bcdcdaeea3aba34a8083bb62c6eda69ff3c3eab5 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary wddx 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length => 32 => 32
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /var/lib/php5 => /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 7236b8a1b3ceee314ed7ab9e0c582a0e8f048e25 $
Schema support => enabled

soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 6360183f0075ec66a3dfa01633b2ed808dd482af $

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.8.0

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id$
Zip version => 1.11.0
Libzip version => 0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.1.1
Linked Version => 1.2.7

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm

Environment

Variable => Value
LC_PAPER => en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS => en_US.UTF-8
SSH_AGENT_PID => 1790
LC_MONETARY => en_US.UTF-8
GPG_AGENT_INFO => /run/user/codevelop/keyring-c09Hgb/gpg:0:1
TERM => xterm
SHELL => /bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE => dcfb27ee6cecf6a058a3e535520d0b3a-1379434661.310356-1959199193
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT => stderr
WINDOWID => 41943045
LC_NUMERIC => en_US.UTF-8
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL => /run/user/codevelop/keyring-c09Hgb
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS => JS ERROR;JS LOG
USER => codevelop
LC_TELEPHONE => en_US.UTF-8
SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /run/user/codevelop/keyring-c09Hgb/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER => local/vaz-softengineer:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1713,unix/vaz-softengineer:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1713
USERNAME => codevelop
DEFAULTS_PATH => /usr/share/gconf/default.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS => /etc/xdg/xdg-default:/etc/xdg
PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION => default
LC_IDENTIFICATION => en_US.UTF-8
PWD => /home/codevelop
GNOME_KEYRING_PID => 1637
LANG => en_US.UTF-8
MANDATORY_PATH => /usr/share/gconf/default.mandatory.path
LC_MEASUREMENT => en_US.UTF-8
MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION => local
SHLVL => 1
HOME => /home/codevelop
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID => this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME => codevelop
XDG_DATA_DIRS => /usr/share/default:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/mdm/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS => unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-dFJ42ntjlL,guid=9980a7cc2248627fe6212bda523880a5
MDMSESSION => default
WINDOWPATH => 8
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/codevelop
DISPLAY => :0
MDM_LANG => en_US.UTF-8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP => GNOME
LC_TIME => en_US.UTF-8
COLORTERM => gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY => /home/codevelop/.Xauthority
LC_NAME => en_US.UTF-8
_ => /usr/bin/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["LC_PAPER"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["LC_ADDRESS"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["SSH_AGENT_PID"] => 1790
_SERVER["LC_MONETARY"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["GPG_AGENT_INFO"] => /run/user/codevelop/keyring-c09Hgb/gpg:0:1
_SERVER["TERM"] => xterm
_SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
_SERVER["XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"] => dcfb27ee6cecf6a058a3e535520d0b3a-1379434661.310356-1959199193
_SERVER["GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT"] => stderr
_SERVER["WINDOWID"] => 41943045
_SERVER["LC_NUMERIC"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL"] => /run/user/codevelop/keyring-c09Hgb
_SERVER["GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS"] => JS ERROR;JS LOG
_SERVER["USER"] => codevelop
_SERVER["LC_TELEPHONE"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["SSH_AUTH_SOCK"] => /run/user/codevelop/keyring-c09Hgb/ssh
_SERVER["SESSION_MANAGER"] => local/vaz-softengineer:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1713,unix/vaz-softengineer:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1713
_SERVER["USERNAME"] => codevelop
_SERVER["DEFAULTS_PATH"] => /usr/share/gconf/default.default.path
_SERVER["XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"] => /etc/xdg/xdg-default:/etc/xdg
_SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
_SERVER["DESKTOP_SESSION"] => default
_SERVER["LC_IDENTIFICATION"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["PWD"] => /home/codevelop
_SERVER["GNOME_KEYRING_PID"] => 1637
_SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["MANDATORY_PATH"] => /usr/share/gconf/default.mandatory.path
_SERVER["LC_MEASUREMENT"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION"] => local
_SERVER["SHLVL"] => 1
_SERVER["HOME"] => /home/codevelop
_SERVER["GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID"] => this-is-deprecated
_SERVER["LOGNAME"] => codevelop
_SERVER["XDG_DATA_DIRS"] => /usr/share/default:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/mdm/
_SERVER["DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"] => unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-dFJ42ntjlL,guid=9980a7cc2248627fe6212bda523880a5
_SERVER["MDMSESSION"] => default
_SERVER["WINDOWPATH"] => 8
_SERVER["XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"] => /run/user/codevelop
_SERVER["DISPLAY"] => :0
_SERVER["MDM_LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"] => GNOME
_SERVER["LC_TIME"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["COLORTERM"] => gnome-terminal
_SERVER["XAUTHORITY"] => /home/codevelop/.Xauthority
_SERVER["LC_NAME"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["_"] => /usr/bin/php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => 
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => 
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] => 
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => 
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => 
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1379456662.4984
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1379456662
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 0

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe try `echo "<p>Hello World</p>";`

Comment: How are you accessing the page? Are you developing on a local computer? If so, are you using XAMPP, or WAMP?  IF so, what are you typing into the address bar of your browser? You must type: `http://localhost` or `http://localhost/pagename.php` and **not** `file:///c:/path/to/the%20file.php`

Comment: You can follow the relevant parts from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9794884/1057429 - make sure that you've installed correctly both httpd as well as php (and opened the relevant port in iptables etc).

Comment: You also need to tell us where you've saved your `.php` files and how you're accessing them.

Comment: if you have linux-mint with a default installation of APACHE(HTTPD) and PHP then you will most likely want to place your PHP's file at `/var/www/html` folder and access them using `http://localhost/phpname.php` and you need to open the `httpd.conf` and change the directory directive otherwise PHP will be treated as non executable. All you have posted above is pretty useless to help you on this situation.

Comment: Hi, Sir. I'm doing this on my computer. If I do http://localhost it says that "it works!" and /test.php it appears the text "test php" on the screen.
However, if I try to run the php from a file or even from my project it (the page) stays blank and I don't know why.
I'm not using none of them, I installed them separately. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Where is your project folder? /home/user/project? tell me path.

Comment: It is on "~/webDevelopment/site/_php/testfile.php". How can I run this appropriately within my project, without having to put it on /www ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I changed my project to /var/www folder and now when I open it through Aptana it does the download of the .php file... however if I open it trough url (/var/www/website/php/filename.php) it appears me "Hello World" as it should.
But the browser is making the download of the file instead of interpret it, as it should.
How can I solve this?

Comment: So, if the file is now in "/var/www/test.php" then try `http://localhost/test.php` in your browser?

Comment: If I do it manually it's ok, but I want to run it through the APTANA Studio IDE, but instead of appearing the page as it does in aptana, the browser downloads the file and the page still blank.

Comment: I think that you have two problems, one being new to PHP, the other being new to the webserver. I'd suggest that you use PHP's builtin webserver, i.e. run "php -S localhost:8080 -t /path/to/the/rootdir", which is way simpler than setting up a proper webserver and doesn't require you to mess with your system's setup.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to install the php mod for Apache ?

```
 sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

> the browser downloads the file and the page still blank

Add the file extension to the `text/html` mapping in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
 AddType text/html .php
```

**References**

- [PHP Install using Apache 2 on Unix Systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)
- [Mac OSX: Using the bundled PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php)
- [PHP Install using Apache 2 on Windows Systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php)
- [PHP Installation on Windows Systems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php)